# C# unable to run executable

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, executable

I'm trying to run an app created with Visual Studio. The only thing that the app does is to open an empty form so there is no complex dependency.
When I go to project `folder -> bin -> release -> app.exe` it opens three processes but nothing happens - its just freezes. I've tried to fix the .NET installation, uncheck the "optimize code" on the project properties and use 64/86 (I have 64 bit), but its still not working. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

This is the application :

```
namespace App {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community and .Net 4.6.1

Comment: Does it work properly if you launch it from Visual Studio?

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean build (Build -> Clean Solution) and starting it than?

Comment: is it running in task manager?

Comment: Try disabling antivirus?

Comment: It run properly on VS, I've tried to clean and then build, It is running on task manager, and the problem was indeed the anti virus! Thanks Martheen!